# displaying array in tree format

Tags: php

Its a simple problem but I think i am stuck..I need to get the array's elements to be displayed in a tree format in php.. the array elements will be fetched from the database..

Comment: Like a menu with submenus?  And do you have a database schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursively iterate over the array, test for arrayness with is_array(), other wise print out.  Modify for whether you want preorder, inorder, or postorder. Done.